# UIPickerView with UIToolBar issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I'm having an issue with a UIPickerView with a UIToolBar that has a **Done** button. The thing is that the button **Done** sometimes is showed in blue (normal behavior) and other times the button appear in a sheer grey that is difficult to see (See picture attached).

[image: Issue with the UIPickerView toolbar button]

The pickerview and the toolbar are generated this way:

```
mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];
mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
statusTextField.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;
```

I've searched about it with no luck.

Comment: Are you testing on the same device/iOS version each time? And compiling using the same SDK version?

Comment: If you create an UIBarButtonSystemItem, it will create a button with blue text (iOS7), if you create a button with UIButtonTypeCustom type, it will show a button with light gray title.

Comment: Yes i'm testing in the same device/iOS, actually at runtime the color changes. The issue is that the color is changing at some point, actually i try with another color like red and at some point is grey again. I don't have issues setting the color at first but i like that it doesn't change.